# can you help me understand why my recyclerview is not being populated with data?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my application am scanning for advertising BLE devices and I would like to display the results in a recyclerview. I can scan for the devices just fine, but they are not being added to the recyclerview. I have created a dialog fragment in the main activity:

```
public static class BleConnDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private RecyclerView bleRecycler;
    private ScanListAdapter mScanAdapter;

    private void loadScanResults() {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "results: ");
        for (final BluetoothDevice device : mScanResults) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, device.getName());
        }

        mScanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG,"bledialog onactivitycreated");
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "ble dialog oncreatedialog");
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_ble_config, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        Button scanForDevices = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan_for_devices);

        mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, @NonNull ScanResult result) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "onScanResult: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " " + result.getDevice().getAddress());
            }

            @Override
            public void onBatchScanResults(@NonNull List<ScanResult> results) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "onBatchScanResults ");

                for (final ScanResult result : results) {
                    boolean add = true;
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "batch scan device: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " " + result.getDevice().getAddress());
                    for (final BluetoothDevice device : mScanResults) {
                        if (result.getDevice().getAddress().toString().equals(device.getAddress().toString())) {
                            add = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (add == false || result.getDevice().getName() == null) continue;

                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mScanResults.add(result.getDevice());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "scan failed");
            }
        };

        bleScanTimer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG,"blescantimer");
                if (scanTimeOut) {
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "stopping scan; devices found: " + mScanResults.size());
                    mScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    scanTimeOut = false;
                    loadScanResults();
                } else {
                    bleHandler.postDelayed(this::run, 10000);
                    scanTimeOut = true;
                }
            }
        };

        scanForDevices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "scanning for devices...");

                mScanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
                ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                                            .setLegacy(false)
                                            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                                            .setReportDelay(1000)
                                            .setUseHardwareBatchingIfSupported(true)
                                            .build();
                List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
                filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(null).build());
                mScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
                bleHandler.post(bleScanTimer);
                mProgressDialog = MyUtilities.createDialog(getContext());
            }
        });

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bleConnDialog = builder.create();
        return ((MainActivity)getActivity()).bleConnDialog;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "ble dialog oncreateview");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_ble_config, container, false);

        bleRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_scan_devices);

        mScanAdapter = new ScanListAdapter(this.getContext(), mScanResults);
        bleRecycler.setAdapter(mScanAdapter);
        bleRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the layout file for the fragment which contains the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dialog_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dialog_padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ble_config_title_tv"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dialog_content_margin_between"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/wifi_setup_ble" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rv_scan_devices"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_scan_for_devices"
            style="@style/MyFlatButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/scan_for_devices" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout for a scan result item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scan_item_tv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the recyclerview adapter:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ScanListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScanListAdapter.ResultViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mScanResults;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ScanListAdapter.ResultViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ble_scan_item, parent,false);
        return new ResultViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScanListAdapter.ResultViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String mCurrent = mScanResults.get(position).getName().toString();
        holder.resultItemView.setText(mCurrent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mScanResults.size();
    }

    class ResultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView resultItemView;
        final ScanListAdapter mAdapter;

        public ResultViewHolder(View itemView, ScanListAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            resultItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.scan_item_tv);
            this.mAdapter = adapter;
        }
    }

    public ScanListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mScanResults = devices;
    }
}
```

In the function loadScanResults I can confirm the result of the scan with this log output:

```
W/MainActivity: onBatchScanResults 
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: null 61:12:97:F8:1E:77
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: null 61:9D:C3:3F:7D:66
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: null 42:4C:D1:37:14:68
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: null FB:04:CD:76:F3:D1
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: xb-14332525 30:AE:A4:76:F2:42
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: null 70:D1:E7:26:FC:8F
W/MainActivity: batch scan device: null 52:1B:AA:91:BC:85
W/MainActivity: blescantimer
    stopping scan; devices found: 1
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan
D/ViewRootImpl@d460417[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
D/ViewRootImpl@d460417[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=74
W/MainActivity: results: 
W/MainActivity: xb-14332525
D/ViewRootImpl@294cfa4[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
D/ViewRootImpl@294cfa4[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 547575401984}
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
```

In my mind, it should be as simple as configuring the recycler in onCreateView and then calling notifyDataSetChanged in loadScanResults. My code for ScanListAdapter is basically adapted directly from the google codelab. I do not understand why the scan results are not appearing in the UI.

Thanks in advance for any guidance or tips.

Answer (score 0):

According to this i think in UI only show one item you ca scroll then show another item please check for this solution please change layout height into wrap content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scan_item_tv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and also please make sure to grant and implement a run-time permissions.
Thank you

Comment: i made that change and the recyclerview the scan result is still not showing up in UI

Answer (score 0):

Can u please check this function log print.

```
private void loadScanResults() {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "results: ");
        for (final BluetoothDevice device : mScanResults) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, device.getName());
        }

        mScanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: i edited my post and added the log output for clarification

Answer (score 0):

There must have been some conflict with how I used the DialogFragment as an AlertDialog.

I ended up reimplementing BleConnDialogFragment in a separate file, commenting out my original one in MainActivity. My approach was to do nothing in the fragment's onCreateDialog, and implement everything in onCreateView. To test, I changed the type of the ArrayList populating the ViewHolders in the adapter to just strings, init'd the string in onCreateDialog, and saw that appear in the UI. I then reverted to the original ScanAdapter, and it worked. here is the onCreateDialog and onCreateView

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "onCreateDialog");
        return new Dialog(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ble_conn,container,false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan_for_devices).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "scan started");

                startBleScan();
                bleHandler.post(bleScanTimer);

                pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                pd.setTitle("Scanning...");
                pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pd.setCancelable(true);
                pd.show();
            }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan_select).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        mRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_scan_devices);
        mScanAdapter = new ScanListAdapter((MainActivity)getActivity(), mDevices);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((MainActivity)getActivity()));
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mScanAdapter);

        return view;
    }
```

and here is where I called notifyDataSetChanged()

```
private Runnable bleScanTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG,"blescantimer");
            if (scanTimeOut) {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "stopping scan; devices found: " + mDevices.size());
                mScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                scanTimeOut = false;
                pd.dismiss();
                mScanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                bleHandler.postDelayed(this::run, 10000);
                scanTimeOut = true;
            }
        }
    };
```